# $ionicHistory.goBack() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I jump from a page  that is not a tab to a tab page.

On the tab page，I want to go-back when the item is clicked. I use `$ionicHistory.goBack()` to go back.

I found a strange situation， the firsttime `$ionicHistory.goBack()` is working， but the second time is not working。

**My ionic version is : 1.3.1**

I have created a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/fenglu09/pen/wWGBge)

to reproduce the bug:

click Go DashPage Button -> click Select button -> click item ->  click Select button -> click item

Answer (score 2):

Ionic maintains the history stack of tabs and menus separately.

**Updated answer**

Insted of

```
<ion-item ng-click="onItemClick()">item 1</ion-item>
```

try

```
<ion-item ui-sref="dash-page">item 1</ion-item>
```

Let me know if this helps

**Old Answer**

Create your own `myGoBack()` funtion

put this in your view

```
<ion-nav-buttons> 
    <button class="button" ng-click="myGoBack()"><i class="ion-chevron-left"></i> </button> 
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

and this in your controller

```
$scope.myGoBack = function () { $ionicHistory.goBack(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my format.，actually，in my demo when click the item I use `$ionicHistory.goBack();` to go back But the second time click the item to go back is not working.

Comment: As mentioned above ionic v1 maintains history stack of  each page of tab and each individual page separately. This is the root cause of the issue you are facing. The team of ionic have mentioned that they are trying to solve the said issue in ionic v2 which is currently in beta.                                 So the only logical solution is to maintain our own login to go back or redirect of page you want to go.                                                                               Hopefully this solves your dilemma

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tab pages ,i highly recommend to have every page as a tab. For those that you dont wish to appear on the tab but would like to use as a page, you can add the "hidden="true" property to

```
 <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" href="#/app/home" hidden="true">
```

The way you have coded your 'chat' state will give you lots of problems in the future. To be better understand states, i suggest download starter apps. A good one would be [Ionic Tabs Plus Sidemenu Starter](https://github.com/loringdodge/ionic-tabs-plus-sidemenu/blob/master/README.md)

Its free and should give you a better understanding of using states outside of a tab, inside a tab-formatted ionic project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply。The [Ionic Tabs Plus Sidemenu Starter](http://codepen.io/loringdodge/pen/vOrRpV) is of great use for understanding tabs。But 'tab  + menu' does’t meet my needs。My need is similar to my [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/fenglu09/pen/wWGBge)